# Boost.Filesystem crashes

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

Does anyone had this problem ? When searching a partition with recursive_directory_iterator, when it reaches the end it crashes.
I get this in Visual Studio 2008 with boost 1.39 but also at home using MinGW with boost 1.46. I don't think I am doing something wrong:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace std;




int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    boost::filesystem::path musicPaths("d:\\");
    for(boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator it(musicPaths); it != boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(); ++it)
    {
        string strToFind = ".mp3";
        boost::filesystem::path dummypath = it->path().filename();
        string str = dummypath.string();
        if(str.find(strToFind) != -1)
        {
            cout << str << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
I see that it doesnt crash at the end but when it reaches System Volume Information

Comment: Maybe it is calling the constructor every time through the loop?  Try the code sample on this page: http://warpedvisions.org/2008/04/25/howto-directory-recursion-in-boost-and-other-tips/

Comment: @ Merlyn Morgan-Graham: still the same

Comment: What happens when it "crashes"? What does your actual code look like? It may surprise you, but people have used `recursive_directory_iterator`, so if such a trivial example caused problems, someone would have noticed it. Can you show us a complete example which can be compield and run by us, which reproduces the problem?

Comment: @jalf: done, take a look

Comment: yes, probably its because i dont have acces to that folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows does not allow you to look inside the directory "System Volume Information".
So unleashing a recursive_directory_iterator on "System Volume Information" is a bad idea.

Edit: You may be able to solve the problem with recursive_directory_iterator::no_push(). From The Boost docs:

```
void no_push(bool value=true);

    Requires: *this != recursive_directory_iterator().

    Postcondition: no_push_pending() == value.

    Throws: Nothing.

    [Note: no_push() is used to prevent unwanted recursion into a directory. --end note]
```

Comment: how can i ignore it, so it won't cause problems ?

Answer (score 1):

You should call no_push() before moving to the next iterator.

Pseudo code:

if(*it is a directory that I want to skip)
    it.no_push();
++it;

Answer (score -1):

## define  HDIR_DEEP_ITERATOR_BASE boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator

class dir_deep_iterator : public HDIR_DEEP_ITERATOR_BASE

{

public:

```
.....

dir_deep_iterator & operator ++()

{

    try

    {

        return (dir_deep_iterator &)HDIR_DEEP_ITERATOR_BASE::operator ++();

    }

    catch(...)

    {

        //有些特殊的目录无法打开，比如"System Volume Information"，导致抛出异常

        no_push(true);

        return (dir_deep_iterator &)HDIR_DEEP_ITERATOR_BASE::operator ++();

    }

}

....
```

}